# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 409 for URL

Tags: java, jaxb, inputstream

I am using some application's API to download documents. Problem is when I try to parse inputStream it throws response code 409 exception. But the biggest problem is it **sometimes** throws this exception. What is the cause of this exception?

Here is my code;

```
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

       if (conn != null) {

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();//this line throws exception

            MyXmlParser myXmlParser = new MyXmlParser();

            MyClientData myClientData = myXmlParser.parseMyOutput(inputStream); 

            return myClientData;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e; 
        }

    }
```

Here is my XML parser;

```
public class MyXmlParser {

  private final JAXBContext myOutputContext;
  private final XMLInputFactory xif;

  public MyXmlParser() throws JAXBException {
    xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
    xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
    myOutputContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClientData.class);
  }

  public MyClientData parseMyOutput(InputStream inputStream) throws JAXBException {
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = myOutputContext.createUnmarshaller();
    return (MyClientData) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(createStreamReader(inputStream));
  }

  private XMLStreamReader createStreamReader(InputStream inputStream) throws JAXBException {
    try {
        return xif.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
        throw new JAXBException(ex);
    }
  }

}
```

Here is taken from application's API to download document;

```
HTTP Request    GET /{file_id}/download
```

I am getting below error;

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 409 for URL: https://5.5.5.5:443/4144444/download
```

Comment: We can't know. Ask the maintainer of the server hosting this API.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought 409 response code is about client side.

Comment: @hellzone **Server** returned HTTP response code: 409

Comment: 409 is normally used to indicate that the resource you're trying to modify can't be modified because of a conflict. And it should have a body explaining the conflict. Your server uses that as a result to a GET request (which thus doesn't modify any resource), and apparently doesn't include any explanation in the body. So we can't know why the server does that.

Comment: @JBNizet When I paste this url(https://5.5.5.5:443/4144444/download) to web browser I can download this file and It is not corrupted or something like that.

Comment: So? It's a server problem. Ask the server.